# Calculating structure or shape of heat map

Tags: python, data-visualization, heatmap

I have drawn several heat maps over time of some data. For creating the heat map I have used the following code in Python:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from scipy import stats
heatmap, xedges, yedges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, values=z, statistic='mean', bins=1000)
heatmap[np.isnan(heatmap)] = 0
heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=16)
```

This produces the following heat map as an example:

[image]

For the time developing of the heat maps I can of course just plot one heat map after another but this gets cumbersome with a lot of heat maps. With plotting the heat maps over time I would like to analyze the shape of the heat maps in x-y plane over time. So, when I can summarize the structure or shape of a heat map in one value I could just plot this value against time and I would have a much more concise representation.

Is there a way to calculate the structure or shape of a heat map?

Comment: What is a 'structure' or a 'shape' of a heat map?

Comment: @BlueRineS I mean how the heat map looks in the x-y space, i.e. the distribution of the values. In my above example there is one "hot" region at the right and at the bottom and so on.

Comment: But the way I see it: "how a heat map looks" is just the heat map itself. So what is wrong with the current results?

Comment: @BlueRineS The current result is fine but I want to quantify how the heat map looks in a single value so that I can easily plot it over time.

Comment: You can't summarize a 3D map "looks" in one value. You can create some kind of summary value, BUT a lot of assumptions will be baked into that value. How that single value is determined depends on what the data represents and what you consider important, but these are not yet clear from your description. Please provide more details about what the heat map represents--maybe there's another approach that'll be more meaningful.